# Light source automatically fitting to object

Tags: light

I want to setup a light source that is automatically fitting to the loaded object. Either by a script or by maybe setting it in a way that it works great for every object that might get loaded (maybe sun or area?). This means that the brightness should be good for every object, however contours and shape should be still visible, so shadows/shades have to probably be visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is different to what you asked, but I think it gets the intended result.

The sun light itself will impact 'every' object without needing to be attached to every object. The sun has constant direction parallel rays regardless of where it is placed, unlike the other light sources that are relative to their position.  So for example, in the following three images, the sun is above, moved just right and then moved far below and yet they produce the same constant result for the object. For every other object I add in the scene, the same sun light properties will be applied.

Adding a light per object is most likely an overkill.

Above:

[image]

To the right:

[image]

Well below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what I asked for. Did not know that this is how the sun works. When I selected it, it seemed just extremely bright. So just to clarify, the position of the sun has also no impact on the brightness of the scene, correct? So in order to overcome brightness issues I just change its brightness?

Comment: I believe that is correct @clel.